# Store multiple $_SESSION variable in php and echo them in another page

Tags: php, session

In the same browser, not on the same domain:

If on the `site A`, I store in session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['fruit'] = "Apple";
```

---

If on the `site B`, I store in session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['color'] = "green";
```

---

How can I echo on the `site C` :

```
// Apple is green.
session_start();
$_SESSION['fruit'].' is '.$_SESSION['color'];
```

---

Is it possible I echo, from another domain but in the same browser, all the `$_SESSION` variables ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: simple answer is No.

Comment: Your session id between `site A/B/C` must be shared, but more important your session data must be stored in some place where all these site can access it, like a database.

Comment: you could use coockies maybe.

Comment: @Federico: was 99% about your answer. You confirmed it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No**.

Long answer: Well... no but kind of yes, if you build two separate apps, one for each domain and send the session from one app to the other over an interface (e.g. a REST endpoint).

Comment: Thanks. For security reason I was 99% sure about the no. I think I will be oblige to make a table for this step. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can.

You need to share your session ids around `site A`, `site B` and `site C`.  Since session ids are usually stored in cookies, you need to transfer these information over all the domains.

If `site A/B/C` are all sub domain of the same site, then all you need to do is to change `session.cookie_domain` directive in your php.ini file like:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

With this you can share session ids across multiple sub domains, like `A.domain.com`, `B.domain.com`, `C.domain.com`, ...

Harder is to do the same thing with different domain, like `A.com`, `B.com`, `C.com`, as you can't transfer over cookies because cookies are limited by the "same origin" policy. What you could do is to make cross-domain requests. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) some approach.

Now you need a common storage for the session data. Most websites use a database to store the session values instead of files, because databases are easier to scale in a multiple web server environment. You can use [custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) to implement database storage. But if the domains are all on same server, all you need to do is to set the same [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php).

Answer (score 0):

Session is limited to particular domain. So, you can not access in this way.

Comment: This is not always true